# Rust macro to convert between identical enums

Tags: enums, rust, macros

Suppose I have these two identical enums (don't ask why):

```
enum Foo {
  A,
  B,
  C,
  D,
}

enum Bar {
  A,
  B,
  C,
  D,
}
```

Is there any way to use a macro to automatically convert between them, without having to write this tedious code:

```
let f: Foo = match b {
  Bar::A => Foo::A,
  Bar::B => Foo::B,
  Bar::C => Foo::C,
  Bar::D => Foo::D,
};
```

Bonus points: is it possible to do it for two identical structs?

Edit: A couple of clarifications - at least one of the enums already exists in code and can't be edited (in my case it is generated code but it could also be from an external crate). Also I realise you can do this with proc macros because they can basically do anything, but I'm looking for something simpler if it exists.

If it's not possible that is a valid answer too.

Comment: Why use macro instead of [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) or [`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html)?

Comment: so we are not allowed to ask why and you want magic feature where you don't need to write logic of the conversion somewhere ? [Oo](https://media.giphy.com/media/14vK3Sc3zepWM0/giphy.gif)

Comment: @DanielFath: It's not instead of `From`. I want a macro *to implement `From`*, I just don't want to have to write the tedious list of enum variants by hand.

Comment: @Stargateur: Correct. What don't you understand?

Comment: either proc macro, or a decl macro that define the two enum and the from implementation

Comment: Ah yeah I should have said I cannot edit one of the enums (it's in generated code). So generating both from one macro won't work. A proc macro will obviously work because you can do anything with them, but I already knew that and they are a pain to write.

Comment: [Fheiq kah, puom.](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/rust-koans/2408/4)

Comment: @trentcl I assume you are in a very awkward way trying to suggest that some repetition is acceptable in programs. I agree but I don't see how that is relevant to this question.

Answer (score 3):

If you accept to repeat the enum variants once, the following might help:

```
enum Foo {
  A,
  B,
  C,
  D,
}

enum Bar {
  A,
  B,
  C,
  D,
}

macro_rules! convert_enum{($src: ident, $dst: ident, $($variant: ident,)*)=> {
    impl From<$src> for $dst {
        fn from(src: $src) -> Self {
            match src {
                $($src::$variant => Self::$variant,)*
            }
        }
    }
}}

convert_enum!(Foo, Bar, A, B, C, D,);
```

This could, of course, already generate the inverse direction. Moreover, I think it can be adapted for structs or enums holding more complex variants.

Comment: Yeah this is what I want but without having to list `A, B, C, D, ` (I have more than 4). Still this is better than nothing, thanks!

Comment: @Timmmm I understand that it is annoying to specify all the alternatives, but as far as I know, Rust's does not offer reflection mechanisms elaborate enough to automatically discover all the alternatives for an arbitrary enum.
One alternative (that I would avoid) might be `transmute` if you are sure that even the memory representation of the enums is the same.